# Ajax Response Messages Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i have this script that i am running on my website, it is for a password reset system. when i run the script the error messages do not show here is my ajax script

here is my ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#doforgot').click(function()
    {
        var login=$("#login").val();
        var dataString = 'forLogin='+login;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Application/Run/Other/Forgot.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#doforgot").val('Connecting...'); },
            success: function(data){
                if (data === "3")
                {
                    $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                    $("#formsg").html('<div class="alert alert-success-light-text fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><p><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> <strong>Success!</strong> <a href="help/alerts" class="alert-link">We have just an email with a link to reset your password!</a>. Click on it and type a new password and hit change, then just login with your new password.</p><p><a href="help/report" class="btn btn-meadow">Report a glitch</a></p></div>');
                }
                else if (data === "4")
                {
                    $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                    $("#formsg").html('<div class="alert alert-hearts-light fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><p><strong>Forgot Failed</strong> · <a href="#" class="alert-link">The account does not exists</a>. Change a few things and try submitting again.</p><p><a href="help/report" class="btn btn-berry">Report a glitch</a></p></div>');
                }
                else if (data === "1")
                {
                    $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                    $("#formsg").html('<div class="alert alert-hearts-light fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><p><strong>Forgot Failed</strong> · <a href="#" class="alert-link">Please fill in all the required fields</a>. Change a few things and try submitting again.</p><p><a href="help/report" class="btn btn-berry">Report a glitch</a></p></div>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is my php script

```
include '../global.php';
    if (isset($_POST['forLogin'])) {
        if (empty($_POST["forLogin"])) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            $login = $_POST["forLogin"];
            if (forgot($login, $dblink) == true) {
                echo "3";
            } else {
                $response = forgot($login, $dblink);
                echo $response;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "1";
    }
```

here is the functions

```
function checkIfUsernameExists($text, $link) {
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $text);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
function checkIfEmailExists($text, $link) {
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $text);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
function forgot($login, $dblink) {
    if (checkIfUsernameExists($login) == true) {
        if ($stmt = $dblink->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, password, name FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $login);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($forUserID, $forUsername, $forEmail, $forPassword, $forName);
            $stmt->fetch();
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                mailResetLink($forEmail, $forUsername, $forName);
                return true;
            }
        }
    } elseif (checkIfEmailExists($login) == true) {
        if ($stmt = $dblink->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, password, name FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $login);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($forUserID, $forUsername, $forEmail, $forPassword, $forName);
            $stmt->fetch();
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                mailResetLink($forEmail, $forUsername, $forName);
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "4";
    }
}
```

And finally here is my html script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
Username or Email
<input type="text" class="input"  id="login">
<input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Reset your Account!" id="doforgot">
<div id="formsg"></div>
</div>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason it reloads the page and it should not.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine after a few tweaks. Is this all your html and javascript?

Do you have a php server running? your URL in your ajax call should be to a url

I just combined the javascript into the html file. because I'm lazy, just put the index file in the same directory as the php. Make sure you have your php server running.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Test</title>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                alert('asdf');

                $('#doforgot').click(function()
                {
                    var login=$("#login").val();
                    var dataString = 'forLogin='+login;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "inv.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function(){ $("#doforgot").val('Connecting...'); },
                        success: function(data){
                            if (data === "3")
                            {
                                $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                                $("#formsg").html('<div class="alert alert-success-light-text fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><p><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> <strong>Success!</strong> <a href="help/alerts" class="alert-link">We have just an email with a link to reset your password!</a>. Click on it and type a new password and hit change, then just login with your new password.</p><p><a href="help/report" class="btn btn-meadow">Report a glitch</a></p></div>');
                            }
                            else if (data === "4")
                            {
                                $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                                $("#formsg").html('<div class="alert alert-hearts-light fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><p><strong>Forgot Failed</strong> · <a href="#" class="alert-link">The account does not exists</a>. Change a few things and try submitting again.</p><p><a href="help/report" class="btn btn-berry">Report a glitch</a></p></div>');
                            }
                            else if (data === "1")
                            {
                                $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                                $("#formsg").html('<div class="alert alert-hearts-light fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><p><strong>Forgot Failed</strong> · <a href="#" class="alert-link">Please fill in all the required fields</a>. Change a few things and try submitting again.</p><p><a href="help/report" class="btn btn-berry">Report a glitch</a></p></div>');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#doforgot").val('Reset your Account!');
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
Username or Email
<input type="text" class="input"  id="login">
<input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Reset your Account!" id="doforgot">
<div id="formsg"></div>
</div>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hol a see a difference in the code, you included jquery. I did not

Comment: cause my .js uses jquery

Comment: it stopped reloading, but does not echo the error messages

Comment: The syntax for ajax that you are using requires jquery to work. You should include it before your script.

Comment: open developer console (press F12 on the browser for that page). Tell me what the errors are.

Comment: Okay i will, not now. I am not at home at the moment.